# How to conditionally move lines up?

Tags: vim, conditional-statements, move, lines

I have a text file with many lines.

```
test = 
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
... etc....
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
1 text
test2 =
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
3 more text
```

etc

What I want to do is to move lines up starting with a number
and attach them after the first line found (going backwards) ending with '=\s'

expected output:

```
test = 1 text
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
... etc....
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
test2 = 3 more text
more text more text more text more text
more text more text more text more text
```

I have no idea how to do this.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:global`, `:norm`, `:move` and the possibility to use a search as target for Ex commands:

```
:g/^\d/m?.*=$|norm kJ
```

Breakdown:

```
:g/pattern/command " executes command for every line matching pattern
^\d                " pattern for "lines that start with a number"
m?.*=$             " move matched line to right below the first
                   " line ending with = upward
|                  " separator between Ex commands
norm               " execute normal mode command
kJ                 " go to line above and join
```

Comment: same idea with my macro. but :g command would be better than macro. +1

Comment: Vim golf: `:g/^\d/m?.*=$|-j`

Comment: @PeterRincker & Romainl, I don't want the global command to cycle, so I added `:set nowrapscan` before the command, but I noted that your global command starts scanning from the top backwards (and doesn't find anything in this case). Do you know how to let the global command start scanning backwards from the bottom of the file?

Comment: `:g/foo/bar` always goes forward. In my command, what goes backward is the search for `.*=$`. Note that your sample text has a trailing space after the first `=` so it wouldn't be matched.

Comment: @romainl, I noted that your command didn't work as expected in a case where there was no `=` character above the first `^\d` line and the global command moved the first `^\d` to the bottom of the file. So I disabled wrapscan but that stopped the global command right from the start. :)

Comment: Well, my command and kent's macro are designed against your specifications and your sample. Since that's a very specific task, there's no turnkey solution. Feel free to use this as a starting point for your experiments and, maybe, add the final generic solution to your question for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

A macro may help...

```
/^\d<cr>:.m?=<cr>kJ
```

short explanation:

```
/^\d   " find line beginning with number
:.m?= " move current line under the previous line with (=)
kJ     "move cursor back to the line with (=), and join the next
```

it is working like:

(it seems that I typed one more `?` and the last `n` in screenshot, but I won't record it again.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you too Kent! Very nice solution but as you've mentioned, maybe the solution of Romainl is easier.